# How to Activate a child within a script without dragging/dropping a serialized reference?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a prefab named "Wizzard" with child "isActiveArrow" using a sprite render-er. In Wizzard's `Player.cs` script, I'm trying to activate `isActiveArrow`.

I do this with `[SerializeField] private GameObject arrow;`

and then use `arrow.SetActive(true);`

But I have to drag and drop the child isActiveArrow into the Serialized Field.

How can I do it without Serialized Field referencing directly to the children?

something like:
`this.isActiveArrow.SetActive(true);`

Answer (score 0):

If "isActiveArrow" is always at the same child index(position in inspector regarding to other child objects above it) of "Wizzard", then the following code would work:

```
gameObject.ransform.GetChild(index).gameObject.SetActive(true)
```

GetChild function lists all children of current transform. By passing an index inside of () you can access the child object at that index.

Comment: thanks a lot. it's always same position so it will work

Comment: Hardcoding index is rather risky, you need to remember what you coded or else the script will be broken when you reorder your object hierarchy. Consider using [Transform.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) or `GetComponent<SomeUniqueScript>().transform` at parent level with unique names.